# Angular ngrx guard selected is undefined even if data has been loaded

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-router-guards

I've got this reducer

```
on(CmsActions.loadCmsTopNewsSelected, (state, { slug }) => {
    let selected;
    if (state.data) {
      selected = state.data.items.find(item => item.data.slug.iv === slug);
    }
    return {
      ...state,
      selected
    };
  })
```

and this guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.checkStore().pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        const slug = route.params.slug;
        this.facade.selected(slug);
        return this.facade.selected$.pipe(
          map(selected => {
            console.log('selected', selected);
            if (selected) {
              return true;
            }
            return this.router.parseUrl('/not-found');
          })
        );
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }

  checkStore(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.facade.loaded$.pipe(
      tap(loaded => {
        if (!loaded) {
          this.facade.load(this.ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
        }
      }),
      filter(loaded => {
        console.log('loaded', loaded);
        return loaded;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```

it works nicely if I go to the route by router link,

but if I go directly the selected is undefined even if

the data has been loaded.

What's wrong?

### UPDATE

I post more code for a better understanding
By the way, I'm waiting to have the data loaded
when the children route is running by the browser.

Routes
Parent

```
{
   path: 'news',
   canLoad: [CmsNewsGuard],
   loadChildren: () =>
          import('./news/news.module').then(m => m.PublicNewsModule)
},
```

Children

```
{
    path: ':slug',
    canActivate: [CmsNewsGuardSelected],
    component: PublicNewsPageDetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicNewsListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Facade

```
export class CmsNewsFacade {
  get data$(): Observable<CmsArray<CmsNews> | null> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selectCmsNewsData));
  }

  get error$(): Observable<Required<ErrorDto> | null> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selectCmsNewsError));
  }

  get loaded$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selectCmsNewsLoaded));
  }

  get selected$(): Observable<CmsNews | undefined> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selectCmsNewsSelected));
  }

  constructor(private store: Store<CmsState>) {}

  load(top: number): void {
    this.store.dispatch(CmsActions.loadCmsTopNews({ top }));
  }

  selected(slug: string): void {
    this.store.dispatch(CmsActions.loadCmsTopNewsSelected({ slug }));
  }
}
```

Selector

```
export const selectCmsNewsSelected = createSelector(
  selectMarketAccountFeature,
  (state: CmsState) => {
    return state.news.selected;
  }
);
```

### UPDATE2

It workish with

```
return this.facade.selected$.pipe(
          filter(selected => {
            return !!selected;
          }),
          map(selected => {
            if (selected) {
              return true;
            }
            return this.router.parseUrl('/not-found');
          })
        );
```

but doing so I lost the goal show a not found page
if the slug didn't exist :(

### WORKED IT OUT!

I worked it out adding a check in the reducer

```
const current = state.data.items.find(item => item.data.slug.iv === slug);
if (!current) {
   selected = null;
}
```

in the guard simply

```
filter(selected => {
   return selected !== undefined;
}),
```

Comment: Please share your selector too. A question: your piece of state is lazy loaded?

Comment: Please share your selector `selectCmsNewsSelected`

Comment: I've update the post

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Your selector is a const export which loaded eagerly all times, but your reducer is binded with your piece of state and loaded after the lazy load modul is loaded. See my answer edit.

Comment: I worked it out but thanks the same for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your selector tries to select an undefined piece of state, because when your page loaded then your Guard checks the condition faster than your data appearances in the store after loading. This is because the lazy loading.
Your Guard is provided in eager loaded module. Your store piece is declared in a lazy loaded module, this is the problem why your Guard doesn't accept your navigation with first load.

**How you solve this?**

Check when your state is undefined, and in this case return true, and when your state is makes updates, your guard will redirects your user if they don't have access.